# How to summarize all values in column over excluded window in BigQuery and then set results into this excluded window?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to aggregate values over excluded window the get results in this excluded window

I tried this query, but returns sum over whole field

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 'a1' id, 10 value 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'a1' id, 20 value 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'a2' id, 20 value 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'a2' id, 40 value
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'a2' id, 12 value
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'a3' id, 44 value
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'a3' id, 34 value    
)
SELECT id, 
SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id<>id) sum_all_except_current_id
FROM t
```

Also tried
`SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id, id<>id)`,
`SUM(value) OVER (ORDER BY id<>id)`,
`SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id<>id)`,
`SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id, id<>id)`,
`SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id<>id)` these does't work for me.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  And please explain clearly the logic.  Nonworking queries do not provide this information.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sum of all other ids, then you can use `-`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(value) over () - sum(value) over (partition by id) as excluded_sum
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you! So elegant!

Comment: @Timogavk - any reason for this answer not being accepted?!